# How to simplify the error handling in (IO (Either a b))

Tags: haskell

I'm using the following scenario as an example to learn how to handle errors in a simple way. The scenario is basically read a file path from an environment variable, then read and print the file with the file path.

The following code works, but I don't like the `printFile` because it has nested `case of`, a bit hard to read. I wonder if there is a clean way to get rid of it and keep the `printFile` function flat without using `lookupEnv`?

How would you simplify this error handling flow?

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception (IOException, handle, throw)
import System.Environment (getEnv)
import System.IO.Error (isDoesNotExistError)

data MissingError
  = MissingEnv String
  | MissingFile String
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  eitherFile <- printFile
  either print print eitherFile

getEnv' :: String -> MissingError -> IO (Either MissingError String)
getEnv' env err = handle (missingEnv err) $ Right <$> (getEnv env)

readFile' :: FilePath -> MissingError -> IO (Either MissingError String)
readFile' path err = handle (missingFile err) $ Right <$> (readFile path)

missingEnv :: MissingError -> IOException -> IO (Either MissingError String)
missingEnv err = const $ return $ Left err

missingFile :: MissingError -> IOException -> IO (Either MissingError String)
missingFile err e
  | isDoesNotExistError e = return $ Left err
  | otherwise = throw e

printFile :: IO (Either MissingError String)
printFile = do
  eitherFilePath <- getEnv' "FOLDER" (MissingEnv "FOLDER")
  case eitherFilePath of
    Left err -> return $ Left err
    Right path -> readFile' path (MissingFile path)
```

Comment: Take a look to monad transformers. `EitherT` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @LuisMorillo There's no `EitherT` in the `transformers` package; it's called `ExceptT`. See e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3ded39/why_cant_we_have_an_eithert_in_transformers/

Comment: @MarkSeemann my fault. I searched for EitherT and turns out that exists in `Control.Monad.Trans.Either `. Don't know if it has the same functionality

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `ExceptT` monad transformer for this. I haven't tried to run the following proposed changes, but it compiles, so I hope it works.

First, import the module that contains `ExceptT`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
```

Next, change the `printFile` function:

```
printFile :: IO (Either MissingError String)
printFile = runExceptT $ do
  path <- ExceptT $ getEnv' "FOLDER" (MissingEnv "FOLDER")
  ExceptT $ readFile' path (MissingFile path)
```

You have functions that return `IO (Either MissingError String)`, so wrapping them in `ExceptT` gives you `do` notation that enables you to access the `String` embedded in what's effectively `ExcepT MissingError IO String`.

Then unwrap the `ExceptT` return value with `runExceptT`.

Answer (score 8):

The suggestion to use `ExceptT` is of course a good one but IMHO the proposed answer is still somewhat verbose and you can go a bit farther by simply "staying" in the `ExceptT` monad throughout your code. Also I would not recommend handling IO exceptions all over the place. Even with a small code base you would lose oversight of your code quickly. `tryIOError` is useful in this regard. And finally rethinking the definition of your errors would also yield easier to understand and a more solid solution. The end result would look something like this:

```
module Main where

import Data.Bifunctor       (first)
import Control.Monad.Except (ExceptT(..), runExceptT)
import System.Environment   (getEnv)
import System.IO.Error      (tryIOError, isDoesNotExistError)

data MyError = MissingError String
             | SomeIOError IOError
               deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runExceptT printFile
  print result

getEnv' :: String -> ExceptT MyError IO String
getEnv' env = mapIOError ("getting env var " ++ env) $ getEnv env

readFile' :: FilePath -> ExceptT MyError IO String
readFile' path = mapIOError ("reading file " ++ path) $ readFile path

printFile :: ExceptT MyError IO String
printFile = do
  path <- getEnv' "FOLDER"
  readFile' path

mapIOError :: String -> IO a -> ExceptT MyError IO a
mapIOError msg = ExceptT . fmap (first mapError) . tryIOError
    where mapError err | isDoesNotExistError err = MissingError msg
          mapError err                           = SomeIOError err
```